# Read Event listener not firing in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth project in react native, Where I am trying to read data from another devices. Reading data using using the following piece of code

```
BluetoothSerial.readFromDevice().then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
}
```

which is working perfectly. 
But i want to use an event listener to collect the data send by some other devices at any random time.
I am using a listener found at https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial/issues/16 answered by **@andrescheca**. the code look like the following

```
    BluetoothSerial.withDelimiter('\r').then(() => {
    Promise.all([
      BluetoothSerial.isEnabled(),
      BluetoothSerial.list()
    ])
    .then((values) => {
      const [ isEnabled, devices ] = values
      this.setState({ isEnabled, devices })
    })

    BluetoothSerial.on('bluetoothEnabled', () => console.log('Bluetooth enabled'))
    BluetoothSerial.on('bluetoothDisabled', () => console.log('Bluetooth disabled'))
    BluetoothSerial.on('read', (data) => {

       console.log(`DATA FROM BLUETOOTH: ${data.data}`);
       Toast.show(data.data);
   })
    BluetoothSerial.on('error', (err) => console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`))
    BluetoothSerial.on('connectionLost', () => {
      if (this.state.device) {
        console.log(`Connection to device ${this.state.device.name} has been lost`)
      }
      this.setState({ connected: false })
    })
  });
```

All the listeners i.e bluetoothEnabled, bluetoothDisabled are firing when i am enabling and disabling Bluetooth. But the read Listener is not firing on receiving data. I am assuming that it should fire as soon as another device send some data. 
I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your device is sending "\r" as the delimiter?  The only thing that I've found which stops the read event is the data not being encoded properly and therefore the `String completeData = readUntil(this.delimiter)` not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue just adding \r at the end of data that i was trying to send to my device from a Linux server.
Thanks @kendavidson for your help.